# How to accept requests from specific domains using Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework

So I have configured my project using CORS headers to accept request from all domains. However, I want to filter out requests in views using user provided data. Let me explain: each user can create projects and these projects have a field called `whitelisted_domain` which is set by the user. When a request hits for one of these projects, I want to make sure the request is from the whitelisted domain. For example:

```
class CreateTask(APIView):
    def post(self, request, project_id, format=None):
        project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
        # Here, I want to check if the two domains match or not
        if project.whitelisted_domain == request.META['REMOTE_HOST']:
            # Create task
        else:
            # Raise authentication error
```

The problem is when I am testing my view using services like Postman or Reqbin, the meta element is empty. Is there a way to securely match the request domain and the user set domain in a view? If not, how can I secure end-point? A secret key header is an option, but what if the requests are coming from the user's front-end, where it is basically impossible to hide credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can whitelist IP's. Then check the IP if it is whitelisted or not.

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = '127.0.0.1' # check if localhost.
    return ip
```

And in your views.py:

```
if project.whitelisted_domain == get_client_ip(request):
        # Create task
    else:
        # Raise authentication error
```

Comment: Shouldn't the views.py be changed?

Comment: you can put `get_client_ip` method in views.py as well. or i didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: `get_client_ip` gets request as parameter and returns IP. Yea, you are right!

Comment: No it did not unfortunately